# Web App with GeoServer/OpenLayers that Allows access to specific Layers to specific Users

Tags: rest, proxy, openlayers, geoserver, wms

Which would be a good secured way, having an Angular/C# Web App to Access GeoServer map layer by specific user, so every user has his own maps that are accessible only by him.

GeoServer Version
2.16.0
Git Revision
1ace4fd0a0fb861fd343435c8cbddc60af793adb
Build Date
18-Sep-2019 10:40

The scenario would be like this:
User logs in to web app, and now, when he is authorized he can view all his Geoserver map layers using openLayers.

I did try to set "Ann New Authority Url" in Layer properties but it throws an error

java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to create a workspace for each [user](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/usergrouprole/usergroups.html) and use the GeoServer authentication system to allow only that [user to access that workspace](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html#protecting-a-single-workspace-and-a-single-layer).

There is a long and detailed [section](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/index.html) in the [GeoServer manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/index.html) that describes all you need to know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please clarify how its done?

Comment: In documentation it shows how to configure security files, but how I would do it through API? Create a workspace restricted to specific users and a Create a user and allow it access to specific workspace?

Comment: see https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/latest/en/api/1.0.0/security.yaml for details of the REST API security end points